# Odd and even with classes instead of html tags

Tags: html, sass, css-selectors

I'm been working on finding a way to change my even and odd setup so it relies more on the classes instead of the html strucktur but am at a complet loss.

The setup i but below works but if there's too much change to the HTML it would likely break.

*(The HTML images gives a simpel overview)*

The collapsed HTML version shows 3 div's but the 2 div is actually a set of 2.

**The classes it goes like this:**

> academy-subject-block
>
> academy-column-block
>
> academy-column-block
>
> academy-subject-block

The end result is 4 squares where the first one keeps it's image from what it had on tablet size screens and above.
The next 3 will alternate between a white and a light grey bagground-color without the images.

---

**HTML from browser view:**

[HTML Viewed from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwJ6E.png)

[HTML Viewed from browser collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEuzI.png)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container academy ">
    <div class="academy-front-page">
        <div class="fullPageAdjustment">
            @Html.PropertyFor(m => m.CurrentPage.ContentArea)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

-------------------------------------------------------------

<div class="academy-subject-block">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="img-fullwidth cover-image">
                    <img src="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.CoverImage)" alt="Cover Image" class="fill-height-image min-height"/>

                    <div class="cta-turquiose-centerallign-mobile">
                        <a href="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.ButtonLink)" class="pulse animated btn bta-cta-turkuoise">
                            @Html.PropertyFor(l => l.ButtonText)
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-block-image fadeIn animated">
        @Html.PropertyFor(m =>  m.OverlayText)
    </div>
</div>

-------------------------------------------------------------

<div class="academy-column-block ">
        <div class="img-fullwidth cover-image">
            <img src="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.CoverImage)" alt="Cover Image" class="fill-height-img min-height"/>

            <div class="cta-turquiose-centerallign">
                <a href="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.ButtonLink)" class="pulse animated btn bta-cta-turkuoise">
                    @Html.PropertyFor(l => l.ButtonText)
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="text-block-image-column-block fadeIn animated">
        @Html.PropertyFor(m => m.OverlayText)
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
//Pulls the section up and down as to remove any spacing
.academy-front-page {
    .fullPageAdjustment {
        @include mobile {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -80px;
            bottom: -40px;
        }
    }

    //Removes images but keeps the size without effecting the fist image
    //And adds new text color to images that have changed
    :not(:first-child) {
        @include mobile {
            img {
                width: 0;
            }

            .text-block-image-column-block {
                color: #{$Color-DarkPurple};
            }

            .text-block-image {
                color: #{$Color-DarkPurple};
            }
        }
    }

    //Switches between background-colors of the images with exception of the fist one (Mobile only)
    div :nth-child(odd) {
        @include mobile {
            .img-fullwidth {
                background-color: #{$Color-White};
            }

            .hidden-print {
                .img-fullwidth {
                    background-color: #{$Color-WhiteSmoke};
                }
            }
        }
    }

    :nth-child(even) {
        @include mobile {
            .img-fullwidth {
                background-color: #{$Color-White};
            }

            .hidden-print {
                .img-fullwidth {
                    background-color: #{$Color-WhiteSmoke};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be more specific about your required solution / output

Comment: The end result is 4 squares where the first one keeps it's image from what it had on tablet size screens and above. 
The next 3 will alternate between a white and a light grey bagground-color without the images.

Comment: Looking into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, this is currently not possible with CSS alone.

You would have to:

1. use Javascript to implement that CSS class based or
2. go with the CSS pseudo classes `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` depending on HTML elements.